# OpenAI API reruning more than asked for

Tags: php, openai-api

I have very simple PHP code

```
<?php

// Set your OpenAI API key
$api_key = 'API-KEY';

// Set the prompt to send to the API
$prompt = "How many people live in poland?";

// Set the parameters for text generation
$data = array(
    'prompt' => $prompt,
    'temperature' => 0,
    'max_tokens' => 40,
    'model' => 'ada',
);

// Encode the data in JSON format
$data_string = json_encode($data);

// Set the API endpoint
$url = 'https://api.openai.com/v1/completions';

// Set the HTTP headers
$headers = array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $api_key,
);

// Initialize a new cURL session
$ch = curl_init();

// Set the cURL options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

// Send the HTTP request and get the response
$response = curl_exec($ch);

// Check for any errors
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
} else {
    // Print the response data
    $response_data = json_decode($response, true);
    echo $response_data['choices'][0]['text'];
    // echo '<pre>';
    // print_r($response_data);
}

// Close the cURL session
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Fo basic question like at example "How many people live in poland?" I everytime except answer getting another random questions and answers. Is this the right model endpoint for use? I just want answers, no additional questions to my prompt.

Comment: I think you should be using the `chatcompletion` endpoint, not `completions`.

Comment: https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/chat